# Multi-value Parameter missing value ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I have multiple datasets in a report. There is one main dataset which brings in all the Contacts that follow criteria which I then pass to one of my multi-value parameters i.e. `ContactIDs` by selecting its available and default values to be derived from the main dataset.

Other datasets have a condition built in that they should bring data only related to the contacts in `ContactIDs` parameter.

Everything is fine until the main dataset returns any records. The moment there is no data or contacts I get an error saying "Parameter `ContactIDs` is missing a value

I have seen a lot of workarounds which suggest putting a default value in the parameter but I don't see an option to putting a default value and getting rest of the values from the query.

#### Major consideration

The query is **not** SQL, instead its FetchXML so there is no scope for me to return a blank or zero or anything if there are no records.

Any suggestions?

Comment: By any chance did you found any way around this?